# How to extend /dev/sda5

Tags: linux, command-line, partition, webserver, administration

How to extend the specified partition in ubuntu 22 dev/sda5

It will help a lot in my case if someone help

Thanks[image: my linux partition]

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). The same information can be conveyed using `fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `fdisk` to delete partitions `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda5`, then re-create `/dev/sda5` as a primary partition starting at the same sector as the original partitions and extending to the end of the disk. Then, if the file system type allows it, extend the file system with the right tool. `resize2fs` or `xfs_growxfs` are good options. You might be out of luck if you use a different filesystem.

You probably want to back up your system before taking any actions on the disk partitions.

Comment: there's no need to delete sda2 or sda5. just increase sda2 first (because sda5 can't go beyond the boundaries of sda2), then increase sda5, then resize the fs on sda5

Answer (score 1):

Because /dev/sda5 is INSIDE sda2 you can't make it any bigger until you make sda2 bigger. It looks sda5 is your root drive .... you are booting from a nested partition? YIKES!

I think the safest way out of this mess, assuming there is anything on sda5 you want to keep, would be to create a new primary partition sda3 for /, do a fresh install there then mount sda5 to recover your files.

Comment: There's no need to panic - booting from an extended partition isn't a problem, it's perfectly normal and ordinary.  No need to reinstall (or delete any parititions as in @doneal25's answer), either  - just increase the size of sda2 partition, then increase the sda5 partition, then resize the filesystem on sda5.